# How to read big rows from questdb with postgre jdbc driver?

Tags: questdb

I can read 1800 rows from the db,but if I want read more there throw the error "An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.". And I also can't use the PreparedStatement to insert message to db.
This is my pg configure for questdb.

```
pg.enabled=true
pg.net.active.connection.limit=1000
pg.net.bind.to=0.0.0.0:8812
pg.net.event.capacity=1024
pg.net.io.queue.capacity=1024
pg.net.idle.timeout=300000
pg.net.interest.queue.capacity=1024
pg.net.listen.backlog=50000
pg.net.recv.buf.size=-1
pg.net.send.buf.size=-1
pg.character.store.capacity=4096
pg.character.store.pool.capacity=64
pg.connection.pool.capacity=64
pg.password=quest
pg.user=admin
pg.factory.cache.column.count=16
pg.factory.cache.row.count=16
pg.idle.recv.count.before.giving.up=10000
pg.idle.send.count.before.giving.up=10000
pg.max.blob.size.on.query=5120k
pg.recv.buffer.size=10M
pg.send.buffer.size=10M
pg.date.locale=en
pg.timestamp.locale=en
pg.worker.count=2
#pg.worker.affinity=-1,-1;
pg.halt.on.error=false
pg.daemon.pool=true
```

Comment: Are you having error after reading 1800 rows or a row with > 1800 chars?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing Questdb's logs nor error message from JDBC driver I am going to attempt to suggest trying a new version released just recently.

```
docker pull questdb/questdb:5.0.5.4-linux-amd64
```

It has several PostgreSQL wire related bugs fixed. One of those edge case with TCP fragmentation, where TCP connection can be abruptly terminated by questdb and JDBC driver would produce "An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend"